# How to do best ' distribution by' Greenplum?

Tags: database-design, distributed-system, greenplum, segment

For a cluster of 8 segments, design a calendar ( calendar_dt, month_nm, day_of_week_nm,holiday_flg )
and a table with
deposits( deposit_id,cuxtomer_id,term, amount, open_dt(the field, which is fk for calendar) ) 
so as to maximize the performance of analytical
Requests, placement on the study of the behavior of clients depending on the day
of the week.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, your distribution key should be the key used to join with other tables.   So, if the open_dt column in the deposit table is the same as the calendar_dt column in the calendar table, the calendar table should be distributed by calendar_dt.

If you are primarily going to be grouping on the day_of_week column, you might make the calendar table columnar.

Hope this helps.
Jim

Comment: The rule of thumb is to distribute the table by the natural key of the table so you get even distribution.  So for a calendar dimension, you would distribute by the lowest grain column (calendar_dt) and for deposits, you would distribute by (deposit_id).